# lifetime of function call argument

Tags: c, lifetime

What is the lifetime of a value created within the parenthesis of a function call (in C)?

In my concrete case, I'm using vectors from the GNU Scientific Library (GSL) and want to add a subvector of one vector to another vector.
The [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/vectors.html#vector-views) states that

> the elements of the view can be accessed as a gsl_vector using the vector component of the view object

but that I need to take care of the scope:

> When using this pointer it is important to ensure that the view itself remains in scope—the simplest way to do so is by always writing the pointer as `&view.vector`, and never storing this value in another variable.

This requirement is clear because otherwise the `vector` inside of the `view` (which I have an address of) got deleted.

In my case with the addiditon, the code would look sth like this:

```
gsl_vector* long_vector = gsl_vector_alloc(1000);
// some stuff with that long_vector
gsl_vector* short_vector = gsl_vector_calloc(10);

gsl_vector_add(short_vector, &gsl_vector_subvector(long_vector, 100, 10).vector); // offset 100, length 10
```

Is the last line a save operation although I'm not explicitly storing the returned `view` object?
I expect the created `view` value to exist until the function has returned, but I'm not quite sure about that, because only an address from inside that `struct` is returned.

Otherwise, I can still do

```
gsl_vector_view dummy_name = gsl_vector_subvector(long_vector, 100, 10);
gsl_vector_add(short_vector, &dummy_name.vector); // offset 100, length 10
```

but the first one looks much nicer to me.

Comment: This is a fundamental language property, and is not related to gsl. Does this answer your question? [When exactly does the destruction of a temporary object happen in a function call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37946437/when-exactly-does-the-destruction-of-a-temporary-object-happen-in-a-function-cal)

Comment: If `gsl_vector_subvector` is returning a value of structure type, it is an object with temporary lifetime that ends when evaluation of the containing full expression ends (C 2018 6.2.4 8). The full expression of an argument to a function call inside a statement expression would be the whole expression of the expression statement (C 2018 6.8 4).

Comment: Also note that the documentation you cite is incorrect to refer to scope. The issue is lifetime (when an object exists, that is, the time during program execution when memory is reserved for it), not scope (where in source code an identifier is visible).

Comment: @UnslanderMonica yes, that I was searching for... temporary was the missing word in the search :)

Comment: @EricPostpischil yes I noticed that too... My first draft of the question also used scope, but as you maybe noticed, I've changed it to lifetime

Comment: @EricPostpischil and gcc doesn't even like the & of the temporary value...